# Turn off Spring boot OAuth in selected profile

Tags: java, oauth, oauth-2.0, spring-boot

I have an API written in Spring boot which uses OAuth to authorize all request coming to it.

I am using  the Spring OAuth2:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And the following setting in the `application.properties`:

```
security.oauth2.client.client-id: xxxx
security.oauth2.client.client-secret: xxxx
security.oauth2.client.scope: read,write
```

I am running the API in various different profiles ("live", "development", "staging" etc.) and I would like to disable the OAuth in some of them. It it possible to do so without removing the maven dependency (by adding something to the application-development.properties perhaps?).

I did not find any straight forward way how to do this so far. I choose the context programatically during application launch but this does not seem like a Spring way of doing  this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make 3 `application-${profile}.properties` files like

```
application-live.properties
application-development.properties
application-staging.properties
```

then you can add the properties of OAuth in profiles you want only.
check this [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-change-configuration-depending-on-the-environment)

Comment: I was thinking about doing it this way but if I leave the configuration in some of the profiles and I omit them in the profile in which I want to disable oauth, it falls back to some auto-generated default credentials and still requires me to use them.

Comment: you can add @Profile on configuration class with profiles you want, then it will not be loaded for others profiles, for ex. @Profile("production")

Answer (score 0):

Add a `@Conditional`Annotation to the Configuration-Class which is annotated with `@EnableOAuth2Sso`

Comment: I do not have any class with this annotation. It seems to work just fine without it...